# doughnutChart no color

Tags: angular, charts

i used forEach to push data to show in doughnutChar i have data and label but no colors and last data in array is undefine

like this :

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul1BB.png)

and this is my code TS :

```
public DataChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
 
];

public DataChartLabels: Label[] = [];
public doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';

  get_all():void{
 this.projectService.find_all_project().subscribe({next:data =>{

  data.forEach(li => {
    this.DataChartData.push(li.visitor);
   console.log(li.visitor)
     this.DataChartLabels.push(li.title)
   console.log(li.title)
    
  });
 }})
}
```

and this is code on html:

```
<div class="chart-wrapper" >
    <canvas baseChart
    [data]="DataChartData"
    [labels]="DataChartLabels"
    [chartType]="doughnutChartType">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

if you look in photo you will understand my problem

maybe i forgot something or whatever .. please help i tired from chart.js with angular but i need solve it

Answer (score 0):

i solve it in my question i used ng2-charts but my answer use chart.js

here my code :

html :

```
<canvas id="myChart"  style="width: 300px  !important;" style="height: 300px  !important;"></canvas>
```

chart TS :

```
chart():void{

  this.projectService.find_all_project().subscribe({next:data =>{
    data.forEach(li => {
     this.Data.push(li.visitor);
     console.log( li.visitor)

      this.Labels.push(li.title)
    console.log(li.title)   
  const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type:'pie', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
      data:{
        labels: this.Labels,
        datasets:[{
          label:'comments',
          data: this.Data,
          //backgroundColor:'green',
          backgroundColor:[
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
          ],
          borderWidth:2,
          borderColor:'#777',
          hoverBorderWidth:4,
          hoverBorderColor:'#000'
        }]
      },
      options:{
        title:{
          display:true,
          text:' Larger visitor in page',
          
          fontSize:30
        },
        legend:{
          display:true,
          position:'right',
          labels:{
            fontColor:'#000'
          }
        },
        layout:{
          padding:{
            left:50,
            right:0,
            bottom:0,
            top:15
          }
        },
        tooltips:{
          enabled:true
        }
      }
  });
});
}})

}
```